# Get items and index of dynamic comboBox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, combobox

I have created a list of eight dynamic comboBoxes through the function combox1Gen() and then i have loaded items to them from a text file of values through function loadComboboxItems(). On every respective comboBox's item selection i need to display the value and its index. what code should in put inside ComboTName_SelectedIndexChanged()?
One more issue is there. My comboBoxes with items get loaded very slowly in a hanging way. whats wrong with my code?
My code is below:

```
Public ComboBoxesTname As New List(Of ComboBox)


       Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While i <= 7
            Combo1Gen(i)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        loadComboboxItems()   



Private Function Combo1Gen(ByVal n As Integer) As Boolean
        Try 
            Dim newCombo As New ComboBox
            With newCombo
                .Name = "MyComboBox1" & n.ToString
                .Left = 110
                .Top = 120 + (52 * n) + 20
                .Width = 180
                .Height = 20
                .Visible = True
            End With
            ComboBoxesTname.Add(newCombo) 
            GroupBox1.Controls.Add(newCombo)
            GroupBox1.AutoSize = True
            AddHandler newCombo.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboTName_SelectedIndexChanged
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

       Private Function loadComboboxItems() As Boolean
        Try

            Dim listT As New List(Of String)()
            listT = ReadVars.readVars(GetFolderPath.GetFolderPath("\vars\"), "items.txt")
            For i = 0 To ComboBoxesTname.Count - 1
                ComboBoxesTname(i).Items.AddRange(listT.ToArray)
            Next
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & Err.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function

Private Sub ComboTName_SelectedIndexChanged()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you want to do in `SelectIndexChanged` but I showed how to get the values from the combo that was clicked.

See comments and explanations in line.

```
Public ComboBoxesTname As New List(Of ComboBox)

Private Sub LoadCombos()
    For i = 0 To 7
        Combo1Gen(i)
    Next
    loadComboboxItems()
End Sub

'Since you never use the return value I changed this to a Sub
Private Sub Combo1Gen(ByVal n As Integer)
    Dim newCombo As New ComboBox
    With newCombo
        .Name = "MyComboBox1" & n.ToString
        .Left = 110
        .Top = 10 + (52 * n) + 20
        .Width = 180
        .Height = 20
        .Visible = True
    End With
    ComboBoxesTname.Add(newCombo)
    GroupBox1.Controls.Add(newCombo)
    GroupBox1.AutoSize = True
    AddHandler newCombo.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboTName_SelectedIndexChanged
End Sub

'Since I don't have access to ReadVars I created an arbitrary array to test
Private listT As String() = {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"}
'You should have readVars return an array of strings
'Create this once as a Form level variable so you don't have to read the file over and over
'Private listT As String() = ReadVars.readVars(GetFolderPath.GetFolderPath("\vars\"), "items.txt")

'Since you never use the return value I changed this to a Sub
Private Sub loadComboboxItems()
    For i = 0 To ComboBoxesTname.Count - 1
        ComboBoxesTname(i).Items.AddRange(listT)
    Next
End Sub

'Added the appropriate parameters
Private Sub ComboTName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Cast sender to a ComboBox so we can use the Properties of a ComboBox
    Dim Combo = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim Name = Combo.Name
    Dim Item = Combo.SelectedItem
    MessageBox.Show($"The selected item in {Name} is {Item}")
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadCombos()
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

In response to your question in comments. I added a `Function` and a few changes to `ComboTName_SelectedIndexChanged`

```
Private Sub ComboTName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Cast sender to a ComboBox so we can use the Properties of a ComboBox
    Dim Combo = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim Name = Combo.Name
    Dim N As Integer = GetValueOfN(Name)
    Dim Item = Combo.SelectedItem
    MessageBox.Show($"The selected item in {Name} is {Item} The number of the combo cox is {N}")
End Sub

Private Function GetValueOfN(ComboName As String) As Integer
    Dim NumString = ComboName.Substring(ComboName.IndexOf("1") + 1)
    Return CInt(NumString)
End Function
```

Comment: Is there any way i can get the value of n?